# Can't run TeX from Terminal in Catalina / What is texk?/"I can't find the format file `TeX.fmt'!"

Tags: errors, mac, mactex, command-line

I use latex just fine, but was trying to do the exercises in The TEXbook and run it via terminal and it just won't work.

This is happening on two different computers both with macOS Catalina (10.15.6 (19G73)) and MacTEX 2020.

Trying to run \relax, returns this:

```
 kpathsea: Running mktexfmt TeX.fmt
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
mktexfmt:   /usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
mktexfmt:   /Users/jess/Library/texlive/2020basic/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt [INFO]: writing formats under /Users/jess/Library/texlive/2020basic/texmf-var/web2c
mktexfmt [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=TeX, skipped
mktexfmt [INFO]: not selected formats: 16
mktexfmt [INFO]: total formats: 16
mktexfmt [INFO]: exiting with status 0
I can't find the format file `TeX.fmt'!
```

Of note: On one of the machines, the first time I entered the command TeX, it returned: "This is **TeX**, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020) and when I ran \relax, I got the single *. But when I returned to it, the next time it retuned the **TeXk** (note the k). I cannot find any reference anywhere to what that extra k is or what it means.

I can verify that tex.fmt does indeed exist in the following location: /usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-var/web2c/tex/tex.fmt

I have rebooted, updated my TeX installation, and even removed TeX completely on one machine and downloaded just the basic TeX package. All to no avail. Any guidance or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.StackExchange! When you start tex on the terminal, do you write `tex` (in lowercase) or `TeX` (in mixed case)? If you didn't do that before, please try the lowercase version `tex`.

Comment: OMG! That fixed it!!!! Thank you!! Any idea what the texk means (out of curiosity)? (By fixed, I mean, that was clearly what I was doing wrong.) How did you know that??

Comment: Great! Only unmodified programs are allowed to be called TeX, so TeXk is used to indicate that there is some extension active. It should tell you which in the log. Look for "Source specials enabled", "%&-line parsing enabled" or "file:line:error style messages enabled"

Comment: TeX uses the name you use for calling the program to identify the format to load. (This is e.g. used to allow you to call latex and automatically get latex.fmt loaded) The error message indicates that it didn't know how to build `TeX.fmt` and you mentioned that `tex.fmt` exists, so the only reason why it would try to build `TeX.fmt` was that it has been invoked with that name.

Answer (score 6):

tl;dr: When calling TeX from the terminal, call `tex` (in lowercase), not `TeX`.

Modern TeX engines look at the name the program is called with to identify the default format to load. (E.g. if the program is called `tex`, plain TeX is loaded, if it is called `latex`, LaTeX is loaded, etc.)
This allows you to call e.g. `latex` instead of `pdftex "&latex"`. But it has a side-effect: TeX doesn't behave properly if you call it with an unexpected name. E.g. if you rename the program from `tex` to `typeset`, calling `typeset` won't work because TeX would try to use a non-existent `typeset` format.

Your case is similar. While your operating system is case-insensitive and therefore allows you to call `TeX` instead of `tex`, this will lead to confusion because TeX tries to find a format with the literal name `TeX`, but the default setup assumes that the format is called `tex` and therefore does not know how to build a `TeX` format, leading to

> `mktexfmt [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=TeX, skipped`